# How to share a MongoDB Database

Tags: database, mongodb, rest

I am working on a website with someone and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to push the db to github and have it work on his computer? We do not have a server yet and what is messing me up is that I need to specify a full log path and that means that it will not work on his computer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoexport command to export your collection in .json format and then upload all .json file on github.

```
mongoexport --db test --collection collection_nam --out file_name.json
After that, you can import same .json file in MongoDB by using mongoimport command
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/